# remove icon not working in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to remove added list using remove icon in anchor tag, but it is removing and again opening the list

```js
    $('.list').on("click", ".remove", function () {
          $(this).parent().remove();
      });
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li><a href="#">List[i]<i class="fa fa-remove remove"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Nimesh yes correct ..

Comment: What does "again opening the list" mean?

Comment: Means @jeffdill2 activating anchor link  when i click on remove icon

Comment: I'm confused, if you don't want to link to anything, why do you have the icon inside a link?

Answer (score 0):

You are removing `a` , use `closest` to remove list item

```
  $('.list').on("click", ".remove", function () {
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Some Value in **italic tag** so that you can click it.

```js
$('.list').on("click", ".remove", function () {
          $(this).parent().remove();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
<li><a href="javascript:;">List[i]<i class="fa fa-remove remove">X</i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: fa fa-remove is a bootstrap icon .. if i click that link list was removing and again opening the list link